# Android NavController move to another host destination

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation

I have a question regarding to `NavController`:

There is the scheme (sorry for my painting, hope it helps :D)

[image]

I have `MainActivity` and `BottomNavigationView` with 3 tabs: **A, B, C**.

When I tap to `A` it opens `Fragment A1` and there is `next button` which opens `Fragment A2`.

In `Fragment A2` there are buttons `back`, `next`, no problems with navigation here.

The problem is when I need to navigate from `Fragment A2` to `section B` the same like a click on `B` in `BottomNavigationView`.

The problem is that it's different graph, how to switch them?

**My ideas:**

1. I found work-around: `requireActivity().bottomBar.selectedItemId = R.id.graph_b` but it's not good idea.
2. I would like to achieve it using `navigation component`. I was trying to do `findNavController().navigate(R.id.graph_b)`, but it leads to crash:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: navigation destination
>   com.my.app.staging:id/graph_b is unknown to this NavController

How to make it using `NavController` ?

There is Google Example project with all architecture:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/NavigationAdvancedSample

And to simplify my question I've added a button in this project, where on click should opens different screen:

[image]

Comment: in Google, example look on file NavigationExtensions/ fun obtainNavHostFragment they use  fragment transaction to swap navigation

Comment: Have you found any solution to this..
and how would you do it with implicity deeplink

Comment: @akaMahesh I did a dirty way, passing callback listener from fragment to the container activity and programmatically clicks the tab button  `binding.bottomBar.selectedItemId = R.id.secondTab`

Answer (score 0):

You graphs are defined in your Parent Activity and thats where you will be able to control them.

Your first way is actually the solution. Your graphs are defined within your activity. When you are inside any destinations inside your graph A (say A1, A2 etc.) they have no knowledge of the your other graphs B & C. The only way to get to the graph is through parent activity, and hence

```
requireActivity().bottomBar.selectedItemId = R.id.graph_b
```

The second way that you have tried will definitely not work because `findNavController().navigate(R.id.graph_b)` is used when you have nested navigation. In other words `graph_b` should be inside `graph_a` which is not your case.

That being said what you can do is just write

```
requireActivity().bottomBar.selectedItemId = R.id.graph_b
```

fancier. Instead of running inside your fragments, its better to run inside your activity.

```
// In your fragment
requireActivity?.moveToGraphB()

// and in your activity
fun moveToGraphB() {
    bottomBar.selectedItemId = R.id.graph_b
}
```

Or more more fancier would be using `SharedViewModel` which I don't think is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

In graph B you can add the line

where nav_graphA is the name of the graph you want to navigate to when the button is clicked. Then you can add

```
` <fragment
            android:id="@+id/aboutFragment"
            android:name="com.mycompany.aboutFragment"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_about"
            android:label="About" >
         <action
                android:id="@+id/action_aboutFragment_to_nav_graphA"
                app:destination="@id/nav_graphA" />
    </fragment>
`
```

to create the action to navigate when the button is clicked.